# Where to start from in image processing?

Tags: image-processing

I am relatively very new in image processing and have a mammoth task at hand of designing a filter as my project. 
Could anyone help me how to start of which books to read? any links ?

Comment: For this to fit in on Stackoverflow, you'll need to be a bit more specific about particular programming languages, libraries, etc.  Perhaps ask on the DSP stackexchange instead? http://dsp.stackexchange.com/ (DSP refers to Digital Signal Processing, of which image processing is a subset.)

Comment: no, this should **not** be asked on [dsp.se] and will be closed

Comment: I am sorry for not being specific its because i am very new to this field. I did see some video tutorials . But all i need is a direction so that i get an idea where to start from and how to approach this topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MIT has some open courseware you can use:

http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/health-sciences-and-technology/hst-582j-biomedical-signal-and-image-processing-spring-2007/lecture-notes/

Googling image processing turns up several lectures from various schools which may be of interest. What language/toolset are you using for the project. If it's language agnostic I would recommend Python imaging library 
http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/

Comment: I am sorry for not being specific its because i am very new to this field. I did see some video tutorials . But all i need is a direction so that i get an idea where to start from and how to approach this topic

Comment: woudn't matlab suffice for this project?

Comment: Matlab would work if that's what you need to use. If you are just looking for general direction, why not start with wikipedia. It also links to textbooks that may be useful. Otherwise, please provide some details regarding the filter you need to implement, since that would be a more specific question.